# Upload more than one file using the Web interface

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, interface

Where I work I cannot install the Ubuntu One client in Windows (you need adminstrator rights). But using the web interface, you have to select one file at a time, so if you want to upload 100 small files, well... That's not gonna work.

It's just a suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

This has already been requested and added to the [wishlist](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/375454).

Thanks.